# Fabric Dashboard - Can I search Crashlytics custom keys across multiple apps

Tags: google-fabric

Is there a way to search for Crashlytics custom key name/values across multiple apps within the Fabric dashboard? We have multiple apps that use the same custom keys, and it would be useful to be able to get these all returned within a single list of results.

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently search across apps using Crashlytics.